# Regex to get multiple capture groups from one generic regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This is for JavaScript.

**My Problem:**

So I want a regex that can get multiple sub capture groups for a string. Right now my attempt only gets one, while I expect 3. Ideally, it should be varied in that it should be able to get 2 or 3 or more.

**My attempt**

```js
let characters = {
  some: {
    test: {
      var: "hi"
    }
  }
}

let b = document.getElementById("body");
let h = b.innerHTML;
let regex = /(?:\$\{)([^.]*[.]?)*(?:\})/;
let match;
match = regex.exec(h);

console.log(match);
```

```html
<div id="body">
  ${some.test.var}
</div>
```

**What I want**

```js
let characters = {
      some: {
        test: {
          var: "hi"
        }
      }
    }

let b = document.getElementById("body");
let h = b.innerHTML;
let regex = /(?:\$\{)([^.]*)[.]([^.]*)[.]([^.]*)(?:\})/;
let match;
match = regex.exec(h);

console.log(match);
```

```html
<div id="body">
  ${some.test.var}
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to match? What is expected result?

Comment: @guest271314 the stuff between `${` and `}` everything but the dots, so check the second code snippet and see the difference between that and the first

Comment: So, if you have `${some.test.var.more}` you will need `some`, `test`, `var` and `more`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, for the example, I'd like `some`, `test` and `var` but I want it flexible enough to get `some`, `test`, `var` and `more` for a string like `${some.test.var.more}` and also just `some` if the string is `${some}`

Comment: Still not clear what issue is and what expected matches are

Comment: @guest271314 my first generic attempt is only returning `var` when I need it to return `some`, `test` and `var` as subgroups.

Comment: Unless missing something the second stacksnippets returns `["${some.test.var}", "some", "test", "var"]`, which is expected result; that is `match.shift()` results in `["some", "test", "var"]`

Comment: @guest271314 yes, that's the result I want... but that's not the result I'm getting in the first snippet...

Comment: Then why do you not use `RegExp` at second stacksnippets?

Comment: @guest271314 I don't understand.

Comment: @A.Lau The same, here.

Comment: At the end of the day, what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to use a *single* capturing group to obtain *multiple* groups in the resulting array. It is not possible with JavaScript regex. See [Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html). There will always be as many groups in the resulting array as there are capturing groups in the pattern (+1, the zeroth group containing the whole match). If you use `(\w* )*` it will match 0+ word chars and then a space and place it into Group 1 buffer, then, if it finds another streak of word chars and a space, the regex engine will match this text portion, replace the contents inside Group 1, and will go on searching, etc.

You need to match `${...}` substrings first (there may be several options here, BTW, I suggest `/\${(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)}/g` to only match `${...}` that have word chars and `.` inside, but it can also be `/\${([^}]+)}/g`) and then split with `.`:

```js
const regex = /\${(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)}/g;
const str = `\${some.test.var} \${some.test.var.more.here}`;
let m;

while (m = regex.exec(str)) {
  console.log(m[1].split('.'));
}
```

Note you have the whole match value in `m[0]`.

**Pattern details**:

- `\${` - a `${` literal substring
- `(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)` - Group 1 capturing:

  - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
  - `(?:\.\w+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

    - `\.` - a dot
    - `\w+`  - 1 or more word chars
- `}` -  a literal `}`

If you want to simplify the pattern, use `/\${([.\w]+)}/g` or `/\${([^}]+)}/g`.

Comment: Ah, of course I should have just used split. I'll double check something then probably accept.

Comment: Just for curiosity, is there a way to not use split so that a generic capture group can output the same as multiple capture groups? Or is that just above regex? E.g. `(\w* )*` would return the same as `(\w)* (\w)* `. I thought the global variable would solve it.

Comment: See [Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html). There will always be as many groups in the resulting array as there are capturing groups in the pattern (+1, the zeroth group containing the whole match). If you use `(\w* )*` it will match 0+ word chars and then a space and place it into Group 1 buffer, then, if it finds another streak of word chars and a space, the regex engine will match this text portion, replace the contents inside Group 1, and will go on searching, etc.

Comment: ah well, I should have remembered split first of all anyway.